# highlight span tags inside div on onmouseup

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to highlight individual spans inside my document body onmouseup. My trouble is that for some reason every element is highlighted by default and I can't seem to get it to work on window.getSelection(). I only need it to highlight the span when I've clicked it.

Would anyone know a quick way of doing this?

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h2>doc body</h2>
  <div id="docbod" class="docbody"> </div>

    <script src="./highlight.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
var documentbody = document.getElementById("docbod");

/* turns every word in the document into an element then appends them to the div that contains the doc body */
function splitdocintowords(div) {
  var divarray = []
  var state = ["hey", "there", "how", "are", "you", "doing?"]
  for (let i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
    span = document.createElement("span")
    span.textContent = state[i]
    //-------^
    span.id = "word" + i;
    span.classList.add("textBackground")
    span.addEventListener("onMouseup", highlight(span));
    div.append(span);
    div.append(" ");

  }
}

splitdocintowords(documentbody);


/* highlights a selected word within the document*/
function highlight (element){
  element.style.background='yellow';
        console.log("selected element")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake when adding event listener, the name of the event is 'mouseup'.

```
span.addEventListener("mouseup", () => span.style.background = 'yellow');
```